# Adding outline to a TikZ Mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I have the following mindmap drawn using TiKZ:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=Gainsboro,text=Black]
    node[concept] {CS Core}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept] { node[concept] {AI Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Theory Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Systems Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Game Programming Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Software Engineering Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Internet Technologies Track} }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Overall, I'm generally satisfied with the look but was wondering how I could add a black outline around the basic shape. Any ideas on how to go about doing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very dirt solution can be to add a black mindmap a little bigger.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=Black]
    node[concept,text width=26ex] {}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept] { node[concept,text width=15ex] {} }
    child[concept] { node[concept,text width=15ex] {} }
    child[concept] { node[concept,text width=15ex] {} }
    child[concept] { node[concept,text width=15ex] {} }
    child[concept] { node[concept,text width=15ex] {} }
    child[concept] { node[concept,text width=15ex] {} }
    ;
  \path[mindmap,concept color=Gainsboro,text=Black]
    node[concept] {CS Core}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept] { node[concept] {AI Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Theory Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Systems Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Game Programming Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Software Engineering Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] {Internet Technologies Track} }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: mindmap with border]

Comment: Very strangly the Game Programming Track border is a little more thin. You can adjust it manually.